Gaps in sumsets and difference sets
a) Let $S\subset \{1,2,\dotsc,N\}$ be a fairly thick set (with at least $N^{1-\epsilon}$ elements, say). Suppose that the intersection of, say,
$$3 S - 3 S = \{a_1+a_2+a_3-(a_4+a_5+a_6): a_1,\dotsc,a_6 \in S\}$$
with $[1,N]$ has at least one large gap (meaning a gap of size at least $N^{1-\delta}$, $\delta$ small). What can one say about $S$?
b) Let $S\subset \{-N,-N+1,\dotsc,N\}$ be a fairly thick set (in the above sense) of the form
$$S = [-N,N]\cap \{\sum_{y\in Y} a_y y: a_y\in \{-1,0,1\}\;\;\; \forall y\in Y\}.$$
Suppose $S$ has at least one large gap (in the above sense). What can one say about $S$?

It is clear that sets in the sense of (a) exist: $S$ could be a union of intervals of length $N^{1-\delta}/10$, say, and then one would have reduced the question to that of finding a fairly thick set $S'\subset \{1,2,\dotsc,M\}$ (with $M\sim 10 N^\delta$) such that $(3 S- 3 S')\cup [1,M]$ has a gap of size at least $1$, i.e., such that $3 S' - 3 S'$ does not contain $\{1,2,\dotsc,M\}$. Such sets $M$ obviously exist.
One could also try to construct examples of sets $S$ by working at a given scale and then adding a single or a few very isolated points to $S$.
Are all examples like this? Or: can one give some sort of meaningful classification of what sets $S$ as in a) and b) must be like?
